# WPF - Displaying Large Number of Log Messages Continously

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, logging, responsiveness

I am developing an application using WPF. I used `Serilog` for logging and I have a log sink that displays the log events in a list box. Incoming log events are queued in the `Emit` method of the log sink and queued log events are processed in the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event.

Queuing Log events:

```
public void EventsLogged(IEnumerable<Event> Events)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
                {
                    foreach (var item in Events)
                    {
                        _logMessageQueue.Enqueue(new LogEvent(item));
                    }
                });
        }
```

Rendering event:

```
private void CompositionTargetOnRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (_logMessageQueue.TryDequeue(out var logEvent))
                {
                    Messages.Add(logEvent);
                }          
        }
```

`Messages` is an `ObservableCollection` that is binded to the ItemSource of the list box.

Here is my problem, when there are huge amounts of enqueued log events in a short period of time, UI responsiveness becomes horrible. Is there any suggestions to improve my application? Or any learning material that I can follow would be really nice.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you handle the rendering event in order to display the log messages?

Comment: Log messages may come really fast and in a lot of amounts. I know that users can't track the log messages in a situation like that, but I dont want it to be laggy. So, I thought fastest way is the rendering event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions that should improve the performance:

- *If* you have to use the `Dispatcher` in order to collect the log events, you should use `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` with an appropriate priority. Note that you should avoid flooding the `Dispatcher` with tasks. If you are expecting to invoke the `Dispatcher` in high frequencies consider to user a different approach (e.g. background thread):

```cs
public void EventsLogged(IEnumerable<Event> events)
{
  // Don't block
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
    () =>
    {
      foreach (var item in events)
      {
        _logMessageQueue.Enqueue(new LogEvent(item));
      }
    }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

- Consider to avoid the `Dispatcher` at all. Unless `LogEvent` extends `DispatcherObject` you can perform the data structure conversion on a background thread or asynchronously (depending on your requirements):

```cs
// In case this member is an event handler, define the method of type 'void' (instead of 'Task')
public async Task EventsLoggedAsync(IEnumerable<Event> events)
{
  // Don't block
  await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
      foreach (var item in events)
      {
        _logMessageQueue.Enqueue(new LogEvent(item));
      }
    });
}
```

- Improve your consumer part: the `while` loop is a blocking operation. You can prevent blocking by using the `Dispatcher` with an explicit priority to execute code when the `Dispatcher` is idle:

```cs
private void CompositionTargetOnRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  while (_logMessageQueue.TryDequeue(out var logEvent))
  {
    // Enqueue task to the Dispatcher queue 
    // and let the Dispatcher decide when to process the tasks by defining a priority
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
      () =>
      {
        Messages.Add(logEvent);
      }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
  }
}
```

---

To further improve the solution I suggest to implement the *Producer/Consumer* pattern. If you use `Channel` you can make the complete implementation asynchronous (see Microsoft Docs: [System.Threading.Channels library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels)).

For efficiency, this example also avoids reading from the queue by handling the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event. Instead the example will start a loop on a background thread to consume the queue.
`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is used to control the pressure on the `Dispatcher`: using `DispatcherPriority.Background` or `DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle` should relief the pressure so that the the main thread can continue to render the surface.

The final solution could look as follows:

```cs
class ChannelExample
{
  private Channel<LogEvent> LogEventChannel { get; }

  public ChannelExample()
  {
    var channelOptions = new UnboundedChannelOptions
    {
      SingleReader = true,
      SingleWriter = false,
    };

    this.LogEventChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<LogEvent>(channelOptions);

    // Start the consumer loop in the background
    Task.Run(DisplayQueuedLogEventsAsync);
  }

  // Optional: allows to stop the producer/consumer process 
  // and closes the queue for additional writes.
  // Because this is an application logger, this method is very likely redundant for your scenario
  private void CloseLogEventQueueForWrites()
    => this.LogEventChannel.Writer.Complete();

  // Thread-safe implementation allows for concurrency
  public async Task EventsLoggedAsync(IEnumerable<Event> events)
  {
    await Task.Run(
      async () =>
      {
        ChannelWriter<int> logEventChannelWriter = this.LogEventChannel.Writer;

        // Consider to use Parallel.ForEach (must be tested because it is not guaranteed that it will improve the performance)
        foreach (Event event in events)
        {
          var logMessage = new LogEvent(event);

          while (await logEventChannelWriter.WaitToWriteAsync())
          {
            if (valueChannelWriter.TryWrite(logMessage))
            {
              // TODO:: Optionally do something after an item 
              // was successfully written to the channel (e.g. increment counter)
            }
          }
        }
      });
  }

  private async Task DisplayQueuedLogEventsAsync()
  {
    ChannelReader<LogEvent> logEventChannelReader = this.LogEventChannel.Reader;

    // Asynchronous iteration will continue until the Channel is closed (by calling ChannelWriter.Complete()).
    await foreach (LogEvent logEvent in logEventChannelReader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
      // Use priority Background or ContextIdle 
      // to control and relief the pressure on the Dispatcher
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
        () =>
        {
          Messages.Add(logEvent);
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't had the chance to try these yet but I will and share the result.

Comment: As you said, I was flooding dispatcher thread with tasks. Producer/consumer is a good solution when used with  an appropriate dispatcher priority.

Comment: I'm happy you could solve your performance issues. Producer/Consumer is perfect because it completely decouples the production side (generating messages) from the consumer side (displaying messages). The consumer does not slow down the producers in case the consumer is slower. All waiting involved is asynchronous. The only critical moment is now the updating of the GUI which you can control/throttle using the Dispatcher, like you already said with the appropriate priority. Thanks for coming back to tell me that the solution works for you.

Comment: The solution that uses Channel<T> is completely thread-safe by default. This means you can use multiple producers and consumers concurrently without havig to worry about race conditions or locks.